# .cpp, которые запускают программу по-безопасному

Tags: c++, безопасность, компилятор

Всем привет
Кто знает такие .cpp, которые запускают программу, так сказать, по-безопасному. То есть в параметры передаем время исполнения, и от какого юзера делать, чтобы эта программа ничего не наделала системе. Такая аля-тест система.

Comment: chroot. Правда это для unix-based систем. А ещё можно в виртуалке запускать.

Comment: В виртуалке не кошерно.

Comment: в виртуалке самое оно. Можно гарантировать, что система будет в одном и том же состоянии перед запуском программы. Можно заготовить несколько десятков образов и использовать. С реальными системами это заметно сложнее.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [runas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runas). Создать пользователя с ограничеными правами и запускать от его имени.

Либо функцию [CreateProcessWithLogonW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: самое главное - так это чтобы по истечению таймера отрубалось. runas я знаю